# How to search for unknown functions in help()?

Tags: python-3.x, helper

Sometimes I'm looking for a function but I don't know the name and if it even exists. I came across a problem where I needed to sort a string. The function that I eventually used by a recommendation of someone on this forum was the function 'sorted'.

When i type in `help(lst)`, i find the function `L.sort(key = None, reverse = False)`

but the function `sorted()` would be easier to use in my case.

so I have 2 questions:

1. what type of function is `sorted()` and what type of function is `L.sort()`. I know the functional difference but I would like to know the name types of the functions. `L.sort()` is for lists so I guess there is a name for functions that are meant to use for a certain type of objects. And `sorted()`becomes a purple word in IDLE so I think it is some kind of special type function.
2. how do I find functions like the purple function `sorted()`. If I know how to use the help function in IDLE on an efficient way it makes programming a bit easier. Is there a list of `"purple functions"`?

i tried to google this information but i could not really find a helpfull answer.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** The main difference between `.sort()` and `sorted()` is the following:

- `sorted()` returns a **new** sorted list, leaving the original list unaffected.
- `list.sort()` sorts the list **in-place**, mutating the list indices, and returns `None` (like all in-place operations).

See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

---

**2**. After typing `python` in your console use:

```
dir(__builtins__)
```

This will *print most of the build-in python functions* included the `sorted()`.

---

In any case, if you want to find the build-in python functions specifically for `lists` then just google. You will find pages like this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: sorry but this is not really answering my question. As i wrote, i know the functional difference. My main question is to know what kind of functinos they are and how i look for  functions in `help()` so i in the future i know how i have to look for functions that i need.

Comment: thankyou. I have an python exam so i cant use google during the exam. What i can use is the help function. Tnx for you answer

Comment: With experience you get to know all the build in functions. Another way is the point 2 in my answer. Consider upvoting and accepting my answer of it helped.

Comment: `sorted` is not a list method. It is a built-in function. The datastructures page describes methods of the list class rather than any functions.

Comment: this is true. I expressed it wrongly. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** The below-mentioned collection of resources and tools makes no claim to be complete and I might have unintentionally missed or skipped over other great documentation or projects. If you think that something is missing please feel free to add to the list (I limited the doc resources mostly to Python internal documentation because I think this should be the first stop on every search path).

---

## How to find information about Python and its ecosystem

You can search the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) directly: e.g. searching for ["sort list"](https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=sort+list&check_keywords=yes&area=default) gives [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) as the top result where you'll also find a hint about [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). Another effective way to search the Python docs is via your favorite search engine and limiting the search results: e.g. `sort list site:docs.python.org` (Google), which will eventually lead to the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html). Stackoverflow is of course another great resource to consider, especially when going beyond the basics.

The following is a (non-exhaustive) list of other Python resources where you can find lots of useful information (in no particular order):

- [The builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) which are available in every session.
- [The library reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) contains an overview of all modules of the standard library that you can `import` in your programs. If you are looking for a solution to a more specific problem you might find your answer here. You can also take a look at the [Module Index](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html).
- [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) covers the basics of the language in a comprehensive way.
- [The Python HOWTOs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/index.html) contain more in-depth information about specific topics.
- [The Table of Contents](https://docs.python.org/3/contents.html) is quite extensive, but using the search function of your browser, you're likely to find a good hint there.
- [The Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/), which is searchable as well, contains lots of useful information too.
- [The Python Getting Started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) gives you a good overview of available resources.
- [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/) extensively covers various Python related topics and it is open for contribution.
- For a quick overview you might also take a look at the [Learn X in Y Minutes page](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python3/).

Now this is a lot of information to digest and it can be a bit overwhelming but almost always the search functionalities have you covered: either you can search the resources directly or you just hit the search bar of your browser or you can also go to your favorite search engine and limit the results to (one of) these pages. Then you're ready to go and most of the things you'll learn on the way!

## Discoverability from within the interpreter

You can use `dir` and `help` extensively on any object to find out what you can do with them (try `dir(dir)` or `help(help)`). The Python interpreter also supports TAB completion, so typing `sort<TAB>` will give you `sorted(` in the interpreter. The [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) (`sorted` is one of them) are available in every session and you can check out what is available by importing `builtins`:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> dir(builtins)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BlockingIOError', 'BrokenPipeError', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'ChildProcessError', 'ConnectionAbortedError', 'ConnectionError', 'ConnectionRefusedError', 'ConnectionResetError', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FileExistsError', 'FileNotFoundError', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'InterruptedError', 'IsADirectoryError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'ModuleNotFoundError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotADirectoryError', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'PermissionError', 'ProcessLookupError', 'RecursionError', 'ReferenceError', 'ResourceWarning', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StopAsyncIteration', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'TargetScopeError', 'TimeoutError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '__build_class__', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'ascii', 'bin', 'bool', 'breakpoint', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'exec', 'exit', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'vars', 'zip']
```

To get a better formatting of the output you can resort to [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) (a function of the standard library):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dir(builtins))
# Here it will print the results line-by-line.
```

### Python's `help()` interface

By just typing `help` in the interpreter you'll land in a dedicated help interfaces that allows for obtaining various information:

```
>>> help()

Welcome to Python 3.7's help utility!

If this is your first time using Python, you should definitely check out
the tutorial on the Internet at https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/.

Enter the name of any module, keyword, or topic to get help on writing
Python programs and using Python modules.  To quit this help utility and
return to the interpreter, just type "quit".

To get a list of available modules, keywords, symbols, or topics, type
"modules", "keywords", "symbols", or "topics".  Each module also comes
with a one-line summary of what it does; to list the modules whose name
or summary contain a given string such as "spam", type "modules spam".
```

As the help text indicates we can, for example, obtain a list of all available modules that can be `import`'ed via `help> modules`; more information of a specific module: e.g. `help> datetime` (which will page the output). As you walk through the `help()` interface you'll find more hints about how to use it and how to search Python. The best way to get a feel for it, is to get started and to experiment with it.

### Advanced interpreter: IPython

Now there are a few other Python interpreters (beyond the standard interpreter) that provide enhanced usability. Among these [IPython](https://ipython.org/) is quite popular. You can use it like the standard interpreter and it also has lots of features for advanced usability (too many to be covered here, but [the documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) has you covered). Referring to your example:

```
In [1]: sorted  # here you can use TAB completion at any point
Out[1]: <function sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)>

In [2]: sorted?  # "?" gives you an overview of the docs
Signature: sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)
Docstring:
Return a new list containing all items from the iterable in ascending order.

A custom key function can be supplied to customize the sort order, and the
reverse flag can be set to request the result in descending order.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method

In [3]: list.sort?  # TAB completion also works here
Docstring: L.sort(key=None, reverse=False) -> None -- stable sort *IN PLACE*
Type:      method_descriptor
```

### IPython in your browser: Jupyter

Now on top of IPython there is another popular project, [Jupyter](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) together with its "Jupyter Notebooks". They are like IPython but using your browser as a frontend (instead of the command line) and it comes with even more features on top of IPython (it communicates with an IPython Kernel in the background, so it's really just another frontend); I highly recommend to check it out - it's great for experimenting and quickly getting to know the language but also for more advanced "interactive" work with Python (which is pretty common in Data Science for example). Here is a screenshot:

[image: Jupyter Screenshot]

## The original question: `sorted` vs `list.sort`

`sorted` is a builtin function and it can be used to sort any iterable (not only lists), the output will be a sorted list:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> sorted is builtins.sorted
True
>>> sorted([3, 1, 2])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sorted(range(5, 0, -1))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> sorted(dict(b='foo', c='bar', d='baz'), reverse=True)
['d', 'c', 'b']
>>> sorted(dict(b='foo', c='bar', d='baz').items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
[('c', 'bar'), ('d', 'baz'), ('b', 'foo')]
```

`list.sort` on the other hand is a method of the `list` class and operates *in-place* on instances of `list`:

```
>>> l = [3, 2, 1]
>>> l.sort()
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list.sort(l, reverse=True)  # this also works.
>>> l
[3, 2, 1]
>>> list.sort(dict(a='foo', b='bar'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'sort' requires a 'list' object but received a 'dict'
```